# How to detect errors while using the `.import` command in the sqlite3 CLI

Tags: sqlite

It seems `.import` will only fail if the last record fails. Below I use `.bail on` and the script continues after the first two imports despite them both causing errors.

```
.bail on
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;

create table x (a primary key);
create table y (c references x(a));

.import --csv "|echo 2" x
.import --csv "|seq 2" y

.print 'Did not bail despite failing to insert 1'

create table z (a, b NOT NULL);
.import --csv "|printf 'a\nb,c\n'" z

.print "Did not bail despite failing to insert `a`"

.import --csv "|printf '1,2\n3\n'" z
.print 'This will not print because in this case, the bad record was at the
end'
```

This outputs:

```
<pipe>:1: INSERT failed: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
Did not bail despite failing to insert 1
<pipe>:1: expected 2 columns but found 1 - filling the rest with NULL
<pipe>:1: INSERT failed: NOT NULL constraint failed: z.b
Did not bail despite failing to insert `a`
<pipe>:2: expected 2 columns but found 1 - filling the rest with NULL
<pipe>:2: INSERT failed: NOT NULL constraint failed: z.b
```